# How to have Doxygen only generate documentation for methods that have a comment

Tags: c++, documentation, doxygen

I would like to generate a documentation of certain parameters that the Save-Method of various classes in my program generate. For that purpose, I would like to write a comment at the top of my save method, and these comments should go to a html and PDF file.

I would like to use doxygen to parse the source- and header files of my C++ project, however by default, doxygen generates a documentation for all the members and classes in my project, which is not what I actually want.

Is it possible to customize doxygen to generate documentation for only one single method which always has the same signature and Name (int Save();), and nothing else? How can that be achieved?

Comment: Are the other classes/methods also documented? Unless EXTRACT_ALL is set, Doxygen will only generate documentation for documented members.

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at [ENABLED_SECTIONS](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_enabled_sections) and the [cond](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdcond) command? Here is a snippet of the example:

```
/// @cond DEV
/*
 *  The implementation of the interface
 */
class Implementation : public Intf
{
  public:
    void func();

    /// @cond TEST
    void test();
    /// @endcond

    /// @cond
    /** This method is obsolete and does
     *  not show up in the documentation.
     */
    void obsolete();
    /// @endcond
};

/// @endcond
```

The output will be different depending on whether or not ENABLED_SECTIONS contains TEST, or DEV.

If this does not help, please clarify your question.